# How to generate JWT token using Rest API for Oracle fusion ERP Cloud in Java

Tags: rest, jwt, oracle-fusion-apps

In Oracle ERP cloud we can login via Rest API using JWT authentication  i.e. Bearer Token in PostMan.

So to generate this JWT token through browser I don't need much effort  I just need hit below in my browser : https:///fscmRestApi/tokenrelay

I will get token something like this :

```
principal    "User_Name"
expires_in    14400000
token_type    "JWT"
access_token    "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsIng1dCI6Ik9aOVBxbnotd0xraERLclQwSEhBVDFVWE1GQSIsImtpZCI6InRydXN0c2VydmljZSJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NDkwMzEzMzcsInN1YiI6IlNBTEVTX0FETUlOIi
wiaXNzIjoid3d3Lm9yYWNsZS5jb20iLCJwcm4iOiJTQUxFU19BRE1JTiIsImlhdCI6MTU0OTAxNjkzN30.iyehNURzZ6drKwrZ30wLMgjWZvNHjtPquB4OqY1URrjb7h_rbaSXyGHVjF83unThl4P9YDc2soTaTtyBTsEdnjHdbmhyTyNeJsaX
iyId9kQRc8aY7FKjc_KN0B4W4ehiZDz_C5Ju0Wj0Zbnws5ps0neBekKaBjz_QQOGKwpHPxcvJff4MqsCeLPZd3e7SdjY3mcOizkfaQergQY--pEYeGPqzmTaz_oTtDKrkG3DatRrWOPnlb4-I6TsYI9ccVxVshZMfhf9O0vP54SvDMfb56Vl3
FP-idskXXYoVVa0artLDE-0_npE0tGZdK-EvHmcyLcJsE7hvv2QnfDFnng"
```

Very Cool....

but I would like to generate this token via Java code / PostMan and not by browser as this will expire after its expiry time.

Basically I want implement JWT for Oracle ERP cloud, we have something like below in our oracle ERP cloud UI

Tools > Security Console > API Authentication.

I know we have to generate hash code using Base64 method but then then what other thing will required to generate token like above via Java/Rest API

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you're using APEX, you can use [APEX_JWT API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aeapi/APEX_JWT.html) from Oracle DB. In Java, you can use [one of libraries published in jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to generate a JWT.